# Color Based Collision Javascript (Cocos2d-js)

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, isometric, cocos2d-x-js

I'm looking to make an isometric game so my partner designed the isometric map (jpg image) along with the map objects (png) on Adobe Illustrator. The thing is I would like to set the player path based on color, for example if the terrain is white the player can go through, if it's black then the player is not allowed to pass. Is this a viable method to do this or are there better methods? Also I'm using Cocos2D-js so my coding is JavaScript

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not experienced in Cocos2D or JavaScript, but using color-patterns is very common on Java game development, and I am sure JavaScript will be almost the same.

Here you have an example that does this:

-Every static int on capital letters is a color. (Each element in the game is assigned a color)

-loadBinary() reads levels.png and creates a new element depending on the pixel color it reads.

```
public class Map {
    static int EMPTY = 0;
    static int TILE = 0xffffff;
    static int START = 0xff0000;
    static int END = 0xff00ff;
    static int DISPENSER = 0xff0100;
    static int SPIKES = 0x00ff00;
    static int ROCKET = 0x0000ff;
    static int MOVING_SPIKES = 0xffff00;
    static int LASER = 0x00ffff;

    int[][] tiles;
    public Bob bob;
    Cube cube;
    Array<Dispenser> dispensers = new Array<Dispenser>();
    Dispenser activeDispenser = null;
    Array<Rocket> rockets = new Array<Rocket>();
    Array<MovingSpikes> movingSpikes = new Array<MovingSpikes>();
    Array<Laser> lasers = new Array<Laser>();
    public EndDoor endDoor;

    public Map () {
        loadBinary();
    }

    private void loadBinary () {
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("data/levels.png"));
        tiles = new int[pixmap.getWidth()][pixmap.getHeight()];
        for (int y = 0; y < 35; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 150; x++) {
                int pix = (pixmap.getPixel(x, y) >>> 8) & 0xffffff;
                if (match(pix, START)) {
                    Dispenser dispenser = new Dispenser(x, pixmap.getHeight() - 1 - y);
                    dispensers.add(dispenser);
                    activeDispenser = dispenser;
                    bob = new Bob(this, activeDispenser.bounds.x, activeDispenser.bounds.y);
                    bob.state = Bob.SPAWN;
                    cube = new Cube(this, activeDispenser.bounds.x, activeDispenser.bounds.y);
                    cube.state = Cube.DEAD;
                } else if (match(pix, DISPENSER)) {
                    Dispenser dispenser = new Dispenser(x, pixmap.getHeight() - 1 - y);
                    dispensers.add(dispenser);
                } else if (match(pix, ROCKET)) {
                    Rocket rocket = new Rocket(this, x, pixmap.getHeight() - 1 - y);
                    rockets.add(rocket);
                } else if (match(pix, MOVING_SPIKES)) {
                    movingSpikes.add(new MovingSpikes(this, x, pixmap.getHeight() - 1 - y));
                } else if (match(pix, LASER)) {
                    lasers.add(new Laser(this, x, pixmap.getHeight() - 1 - y));
                } else if (match(pix, END)) {
                    endDoor = new EndDoor(x, pixmap.getHeight() - 1 - y);
                } else {
                    tiles[x][y] = pix;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < movingSpikes.size; i++) {
            movingSpikes.get(i).init();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lasers.size; i++) {
            lasers.get(i).init();
        }
    }

    boolean match (int src, int dst) {
        return src == dst;
    }

    public void update (float deltaTime) {
        bob.update(deltaTime);
        if (bob.state == Bob.DEAD) bob = new Bob(this, activeDispenser.bounds.x, activeDispenser.bounds.y);
        cube.update(deltaTime);
        if (cube.state == Cube.DEAD) cube = new Cube(this, bob.bounds.x, bob.bounds.y);
        for (int i = 0; i < dispensers.size; i++) {
            if (bob.bounds.overlaps(dispensers.get(i).bounds)) {
                activeDispenser = dispensers.get(i);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rockets.size; i++) {
            Rocket rocket = rockets.get(i);
            rocket.update(deltaTime);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < movingSpikes.size; i++) {
            MovingSpikes spikes = movingSpikes.get(i);
            spikes.update(deltaTime);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lasers.size; i++) {
            lasers.get(i).update();
        }
    }

    public boolean isDeadly (int tileId) {
        return tileId == SPIKES;
    }
}
```

I took this code from cuboc.
The game is used as example for LibGDX, it is Open Source and available [Here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-cuboc).

I´m sorry I can´t provide JavaScript code, but I think this is pretty similar, and fits your needs really well.
Ask if you have any questions, please.

I hope this helps.

(Sorry for any english mistakes, I am spanish, trying to improve my english every day, as well as my development skills).

**EDIT: Forgot to mention this method is valid, but VERY slow. You should use this to pre-load little levels, reading thousands of pixels on runtime would slow your game a lot.**